# Applescript painfully slow

Tags: performance, applescript

I'm new to applescript and was wondering whether you see a problem with my below code as it is painfully slow:

```
set myPath to ((path to desktop as text) & "a.txt") as alias
set myFile to read myPath
set myText to paragraphs of myFile
set rowCounter to 0

repeat with nextline in myText
    set rowCounter to rowCounter + 1
end repeat

rowCounter
```

The textfile i am opening is huge, ie about 1.1m records. The same code in VBA opens it and counts the rows in about 7seconds, it took the better part of 10 minutes with applescript.

Am i doing something wrong??

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

The repeat loop as you have is most likely taking forever to process
And is not necessary to just count the items in the list with a repeat loop.

You have already have a item list of all the paragraphs.

So you should be able to just **[count](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptlangguide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW55)** the number of items in the list.

```
Set rowcounter to number of items in myText
```

Or

```
Set rowcounter to count of myText
```

Also as an aside.

Your repeat loop is not using the index variable 'nextline'

If you wanted to iterate over each item you would use something like :

```
Repeat with nextline from 1 to count of myText

Set thisItem to nextline of myText


....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like this:

```
set myPath to POSIX path of ((path to desktop as text) & "a.txt")
set lineCount to (do shell script "wc -l " & quoted form of myPath & " | sed -E 's/^ *([[:digit:]]+).*/\\1/'") as number
```